# Redirect on a percentage basis via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I want to redirect 33.3% of my visitors to path "/versionA" of my site and 33.3% of my visitors to "/versionB" and 33.3% to "/versionC".

At the moment I only got a 50:50 share, with this code:

```
  if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    window.location.href = "/versionA";
    } else {
    window.location.href = "/versionB";
  }
```

How could I do a random split with 3 redirects based on an equal distribution?

Comment: Just check against 0.33 and 0.66?

Comment: Theoretically, with two IFs you could do this. But this assumes something that is not true: that the random generators of different machines will take the samples from the same distribution. You should handle this on server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work just fine.

```js
var rand = Math.random();

if (rand < 1/3) {
  window.location.href = "/versionA";
} else if (rand > 2/3) {
  window.location.href = "/versionB";
} else {
  window.location.href = "/versionC";
}
```

Comment: @ZorgoZ What do you mean by mathematically incorrect? It's splitting outcomes between 0 - ~.333, ~.334 - ~.666 and ~.667 - ~.999.

Comment: Yes, but you are not taking samples from the same distribution. As each call is made on a different machine. It is acceptable for some scenarios, but statistical tests would yield false results.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Considering OP was asking how they can change an if/else statement from 2 outcomes to 3 outcomes, I don't think that's a concern of theirs.

Comment: Might be true... 

Comment: @JonUleis - what a nice way to say it